# How can we automate Flash element Click action in Selenium?

Tags: selenium

I have been assigned a task to click on the flash video to play using Selenium automation script.

I want to know the proper command for that or any JavaScript code.

Comment: [This](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SRC/Testing+Flash+with+Selenium+RC) should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use sfapi By which you will get a SeleniumFlexAPI.Swc file which you need to compile with your flex application.
SFAPI: https://code.google.com/p/sfapi/
and then you can use flex application by using sfapi functions.
: [sfapi functions](http://asktofolks.com/38/how-to-handle-flex-in-selenium-web-driver)

or 
you can use sikuli-api by image processing its not a perfect way to do this but you can use it 
if you want urgent solution. 
https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/

Answer (score 0):

For this, You have to record this event (click on the flash video to play) using Autoit Recorder. After compiling Autoit script .exe file will be generated. So you can test that part by executing this .exe file from selenium RC.