# Unable to perform click on button using selenium flex api?

Tags: apache-flex, selenium, automation

I have an Flash application which was already recompiled with Selenium Flex. 
Using FlashFirebug i was able to find the locators for that app and i have written script using selenium flex API with Selenium RC, when i run the script those locators were identified but actions couldn't be performed. 
In selenium IDE also those locators could be identified but actions like **click** couldn't be performed. Here i have attached user-extension.js to my IDE.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would find the root cause of your problem:

- Be sure that your *.swf (flex application) was compiled against the [Selenium-Flex API](http://code.google.com/p/sfapi/) *.swc library correctly

  - Run your swf in a web browser with a Javascript debugging console (e.g. Firefox with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)).
  - Using the Javascript console, get a reference to the swf using its DOM ID - `document.getElementById(swfId)`
  - Now, test that Flex-Selenium was complied into your swf OK by running one of the test commands that it exposes for Selenium.  These commands are Javascript functions that are executed on the object obtained in the previous step - see [accessing a Flex app from Javascript](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=passingarguments_5.html) for details.  All of the commands that Flex-Selenium exposes can be found in the Flex-Selenium source in the [Commmands.as](http://code.google.com/p/sfapi/source/browse/trunk/flex_source/src/sfapi/commands/Commands.as).  For example, `ExternalInterface.addCallback("doFlexMouseDown", mouseCommands.doFlexMouseDown);` means a Javascript function named *doFlexMouseDown* (defined in [MouseCommands.as](http://code.google.com/p/sfapi/source/browse/trunk/flex_source/src/sfapi/commands/MouseCommands.as)) has been exposed in your swf.  Executing the Javascript expression `typeof document.getElementById('swfId').doFlexMouseDown` should evaluate to *function* (not *undefined*).  You should also be able to invoke this function without an error - `document.getElementById(swfId).doFlexClick('idOfFlexObject')` where `idOfFlexObject` is the ID of some object (e.g. a button) in your swf.
- So, now you should be able to find the command(s) that you are having trouble invoking through selenium against your swf and test them against the swf for errors in your Javascript debug console.

  - If your swf was indeed compiled against your swf correctly, you will most likely get an error when you invoke the corresponding Javascript function against your swf (the Javascript function, itself, is defined and exposed to Javascript correctly, but an error is occuring in your swf when it is invoked).  You would then find the cause of this error by downloading the source for Flex-Selenium (see previous hyperlinks) and attaching a flex debugger to your swf with this source in its search path.  You would put a break point in the implementation of the command that is failing.  In my own experience, I have had to customize and fix minor bugs in the Flex-Selenium source.
  - If you did not observe an error on the Javascript debug console, you should post the stack trace where Selenium RC fails to run a command against your swf because then it would be likely that something with your use or configuration of Selenium RC (or Selenium IDE) is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to click on flex application through SFAPI (Slenium Flex API)
you have to compile your flex code with SeleniumFlexAPI.swc file, which you will get in SFAPI folder, For these files of SFAPI,
you need to follow these steps [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044001/how-can-we-automate-flash-element-click-action-in-selenium/)

Or [see example here](http://asktofolks.com/38/how-to-handle-flex-in-selenium-web-driver)