# Does selenium automation tool support flex applications?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apache-flex

I want to know if Selenium automation tool supports flex applications. Currently I have some flex application that need to be automated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes.

FlexUISelenium is an extension to the Selenium RC client driver that enables the Selenium RC client drivers to interact (and test) the Flex UI components and methods of the Flex application.

FlexMonkey- open source
Paid tools like RIATest,Silktest, SeleniumFlex

Answer (score 2):

Yes, We can automate flex application in selenium web driver, 
For this we need to follow these steps:

1. you have to download [selenium flex api](https://code.google.com/p/sfapi/downloads/list).
2. you will get a SeleniumFlexAPI.swc file here.

   a.  you need to put this file in your flex application.

   b. you need to add lib path in flex compiler like this and compile the code

   ```
             -include-libraries "libs\SeleniumFlexAPI.swc"
   ```

See this link for more explanation.

[best way to automate Flex With selenium web driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044001/how-can-we-automate-flash-element-click-action-in-selenium/)

For reference of [example code see](http://asktofolks.com/38/how-to-handle-flex-in-selenium-web-driver)

Answer (score 0):

You may also try [flex-ui-selenium](https://code.google.com/archive/p/flex-ui-selenium/) by Google Code. It can make things simpler.